# DaisyUI : how to toggle Direction to RTL when language switched to RTL one?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS and DaisyUI as UI component .

I wanna to change Direction to RTL when language changed from English to Persian ,

I know you can set RTL for DaisyUI in Tailwind config BUT I wanna do that when language switched.

this is Navigation drawer I try to change its direction to RTL

[image]

Comment: hi . this [link](https://medium.com/@20lives/multilingual-bidirectional-rtl-websites-with-tailwind-and-nuxt-bca6ccd2494d) can help you .
for tailwind, you need to install this package tailwindcss-rtl

Answer (score 1):

I'm using dasyui in laravel but test this I think it will help you understanding how can you do this

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <dasy-toggle v-model="isRtl">Toggle RTL</dasy-toggle>
    <dasy-button>Click me!</dasy-button>
    <dasy-input placeholder="Enter your name"></dasy-input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Dasy from 'dasyui';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isRtl: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    isRtl(newVal) {
     Dasy.config.rtl = newVal;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```